# Yet another closest child thread: finding the nearest ancestor of an element that matches a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's an outline of an HTML module:

```
.module
  .module-title
  .module-foo
    .module-bar
  .module-children
```

Modules can nest into each other:

```
.module
  .module-title
  .module-foo
    .module-bar
  .module-children
    .module
      .module-title
      .module-foo
        .module-bar
      .module-children
        .module
          .module-title
          .module-foo
            .module-bar
          .module-children
        .module
          .module-title
          .module-foo
            .module-bar
          .module-children
  .module
    .module-title
    .module-foo
      .module-bar
    .module-children
```

I've got the topmost `.module` stored in a jQuery object `$module`.

Now, i would like to select `.module-bar` that belongs to the topmost module, not including the ones that belong to nested modules.

The problem is that **i don't want to hardcode the hierarchy**.

E. g. i could do this:

```
$bar = $module.find('> .module-foo > .module-bar');
```

Or this:

```
$bar = $module.find('.module-bar').eq(0);
```

But the structure of modules' contents is subject to minor changes. Sub-elements might appear in different order, or become nested in different fashion. Either of these HTML changes would break the JS code, and i want the code to be agile and tolerant to minor changes of HTML structure.

Instead, i would like to do something like:

```
$bar = $module.closestChild('.module-bar');
```

I've found a number of questions and solutions that could all be described as "reverse `closest()`". Here is one example: https://github.com/jstnjns/jquery-nearest/ But it doesn't suit me because it only prevents traversing inside the instances of a target. And in my case target elements do not contain nested modules, thus `nearest()` would select all instances of `.module-bar`.

Other solutions just don't pass the requirements. For example, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051985/901944 relies on `.first()`.

Comment: When you say "children", do you actually mean children elements, as in `.module-foo` as well, or do you mean just the element with the class `module-children`, there's a difference.

Comment: Good catch. I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: Another way to formulate the problem is to find the `.module-bar` element with the shortest path to the ancestor `.module` element. That might help to think about other solutions.

Comment: How do i do that, @FelixKling?

Comment: You could do something with https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/ I guess. It's not going to be a simple selector though.

Comment: A fiddle sure would be helpful ?

Answer (score 2):

You could filter on parents

```
var $bars = $module.find('.module-bar').filter(function() {
                return $(this).closest('.module').get(0) === $module.get(0);
            });
```

That excludes any `.module-bar` nested depper than one `.module`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wkt8/)

or (does the same as above internally, so probably not more efficient)

```
 var $bars = $module.find('.module-bar').not('.module .module .module-bar');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wkt8/1/)

Comment: This still makes assumption on the level of nesting though.

Comment: @FelixKling - It does? One could check for number of `parents()` up to `$module`, but that also makes assumptions on nesting. Not sure I really get this ?

Comment: @FelixKling - Now I'm really confused, but how about checking if the closest `.module` is in fact `$module`, edited the answer, again !

Comment: @adeneo That's not an option. I want to be able to retrieve `.module-bar` of any module, not only the root module.

Comment: @Andrey'lolmaus'Mikhaylov - Huh, so in any `.module`, but not nested in children `.module`, but still in children `.module`, I don't get it?

Comment: @adeneo Disregard that, i had failed to understand your code on the first try. Your solution is valid and solves my specific task correctly. The only thing i don't like about it is that it traverses the whole tree of children. I'll accept your answer if there's no answer that solves the task without traversing deeper than `.module-bar`'s depth.

Comment: Hey @adeneo, my disregarded comment applies to your second solution. It works only for the root module, but fails for any child-module. Try moving the `id="test"` attribute to another module. Your first solution stands this challenge.

Comment: Hey @adeneo, i've managed to create an efficient variant myself! :D Check out my answer below.

Comment: There you go, good for you. You can accept your own answer as that's the solution you eventually used.

Comment: You can simplify it a bit with [.is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/): `return $(this).closest('.module').is($module);`

Answer (score 1):

So i've made a tiny jQuery plugin **jquery.closestchild** that traverses the tree step by step and won't go further once it finds a match.

Plugin: https://github.com/lolmaus/jquery.closestchild/

Demo: http://lolmaus.github.io/jquery.closestchild/

Here's a performance test against adeneo's solution: http://jsperf.com/closestchild#runner . The plugin performs eight times faster and the difference should grow proportionally to DOM tree depth.

Answer (score 0):

```
$module.find(':not(.module .module .module-bar)').filter('.module-bar')
```

But I am assuming that `.module-bar` will be under main `.module` and children `.modules` will be under main `.module`.

http://jsfiddle.net/zsQnH/2/

Comment: You link to a different solution. I assume your solution will fail for non-root modules?

Comment: I've fixed fiddle link. Thanks. 

It will fail depending on conditions. If it has non-root .module as $module variable than my solution will not fail, because it uses `find`. Which works only with inner dom elements.